# What is the best source of renewed energy on longer runs?

Tags: running, energy, energy-drinks, gel

I like running longer runs (e.g. half marathons), but after 15-17 km I ofter need some sort of energizer apart from the water you get along the route.

The question is then what exactly to take, as there seems to several different sorts of energizers available.

I know about gels and energy drinks, but unfortunately these often requires that your drink a lot of water at the same time. I have heard about some fruit gums (e.g. from Squeezy), but haven't tried these yet.

**But what is the best source of renewed energy on these longer runs?**

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Sustained Energy and Perpetuem from Hammer Nutrition can be concentrated into a paste.  With this, you don't really need to drink a ton of water.  But, if you are running for a few hours, you'll definitely want to consume 20-24 oz of water in addition to your fuel.

Another great company is Infinit Nutrition.  They have some very good products specific for running and cycling and can be custom formulated for your individual needs and preferences.  And, these custom formulas are just about the same cost as Hammer products.

I would stay away from the items listed in other answers here especially if you have a sensitive stomach or experience GI issues often.

There is a big market for endurance fueling products and lots of vendors.  It's not just hype.  I can't imagine getting through a half ironman on snickers, flat soda and jelly beans.